Why is Double-Sampling Strategy Necessary in These Linear Approximation Equations for Reinforcement Learning?
Hello, I appreciate everyone’s insights and suggestions regarding my problem. Thank you in advance.
The background of my question comes from the equation (7) from the following paper in page 5: https://arxiv.org/abs/2405.16077 It is a paper in Reinforcement Learning, concerning gradient descent to update paramter iteratively to find optimal solution in multi-task reinforcement learning.
The brief version is:
Suppose we need to update $\lambda$ according to the equation below:
$$
\lambda_{t,i+1} =\left( \lambda_{t,i} - c_{t,i} \lambda_{t,i}^\top {\nabla} J_i(\theta_t) {\nabla} J_i'(\theta_t)^\top \right)
$$
Where the $\tilde{\nabla} J_i$ is calculated first:
$$\tilde{\nabla} J_i^k(\theta_t) = \phi^k(s_i^k, a_i^k)^\top w_{t+1}^k \psi_{\theta_t}(s_i^k, a_i^k)$$
In each update of $\lambda$, we need to two samples $(s_i^k, a_i^k)$ and $(s_i'^k, a_i'^k)$. Which corresponds to the multiply of two gradient for J ${\nabla} J_i(\theta_t) {\nabla} J_i'(\theta_t)$.
In this problem, the gradient has to be calculate by using $\phi*w*\psi$
But my question is:
Why we use two samples to compute two gradient of J and multiply them to update $\lambda$?
Why not update the $\lambda$ using $\lambda = (\lambda - c*\lambda*\nabla J)$ and only use one sample?
Thank you again for answering this question or leave some hints.
